# How sure can I be about data validity when manually checking for errors?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

So I have this huge pool of data, around 1000 rows in excel. I randomly checked 30 rows and they were all correct. How sure can I be that all rows are correct?

If that probability is not zero, how do I assign probabilities to error counts, namely how likely is it that there's just one error based on the above observation, or two for that matter and so on.

Also the reverse must also be a valid question, right? If all 30 were wrong instead of correct, then there must be some odds that at least one other is correct?

Comment: You cannot be sure. The [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(statistics)) might suggest that if $30$ rows had no errors then you could have a confidence interval of between $0\%$ and $\frac{3}{30}=10\%$ of the remaining rows having errors.

Comment: Before checking maybe you thought about 10% of rows might have errors, and use BETA(1,10) as prior dist'n for Bayesian inference. Then you find 30 of 30 rows to have no error. Because 30 is a small fraction of 1000 you might take that as a binomial sample. Then posterior distn is BETA(1, 40). From R, code `qbeta(c(.025,.975), 1, 40)`  gives 95% Bayesian posterior interval est. of proportion of defective rows to be $(0.00063, 0.08810)$ and mean about 0.024,  This'd be promising, but hardly a guarantee of no errors in 1000 rows. // Maybe scan for absurd outliers. If none, hope for the best.